# Loop over individual trees in 'multiphylo' object in R

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I am trying to run functions over multiple phylogenetic trees (files of class multiphylo). Most of these functions come with specific R packages, but are only applicable to single trees (class phylo). Essentially, multiphylo object consists of many objects of class phylo. I was trying to see if using a for lopp, I could run the same operation on all objects in the multiphylo object but I am running into errors. Any suggestions?

```
library(ape)
library(TreePar)
x=read.nexus(file.choose()) #read in file with multiple phylogenetic trees
times<-0
for(i in 1:length(x)) 
{
  times[i]<-getx(x[[i]])
  print(times[i])
}
print(i)
```

I get the following error warning -

```
In ages[i] = getx(x[[i]]) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: What is the output of `getx(x[[i]])`? A single value?

Comment: getx output is numeric.

It is a list of node numbers and their corresponding ages.

Comment: So it is not a single value. How could it work? You try to store a `list` inside a single value of a `numeric` vector.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to sort it. :)